# join lists by common elements

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics

You have N lists

```
A = [5, 6, 10, 15]
B = [3, 0, 7, 4]
C = [49, 59, 29]
D = [19, 29, 39]
E = [9, 15, 3, 10]
```

You have to combine them such that:
Two lists which have a common elements they should be next to each other. In this case answer is:

```
A,E,B,C,D
[5, 6, 10, 15, 9, 3, 0, 7, 4, 49, 59, 29, 19, 39]
```

**E** comes after **A** as they have 2 common elements. After **E** the **B** comes as they have common elements. **B** do not have common elements with **C** or **D** so anything can come (**C** or **D**), lets say **C** comes. Now **C** should be followed by **D** as they have common elements.

**Note:** This is also acceptable solution

```
B,E,A,C,D
C,D,A,E,B
....
```

Thus the main condition is if two lists have common elements they should be next to each other.

**Note 2:** For simplicity we assume a list can have common elements with maximum 2 other lists. However there can be list which have no  common elements with any other list.

**Note 3:** Output format : preferably both, the name of list and the number sequence.

Comment: What exactly are the input and output formats? Is the output `A,E,B,C,D` or the list of numbers? is it always a single letter identifier before the equals? Please clarify.

Comment: @isaacg  output format can be A,E,B,C,D . Does the identifier of list matter !! If so yes it can be more then one letter

Comment: Sometimes this is not possible. What to do then?

Comment: I think you'll have to specify if the number sequence is required or not. Or give a bonus for outputting the number sequence. For a code golf contest, "preferably" is too vague. Also, if the number sequence is involved, I don't see a clear definition of what it is. I think I understand it based on the example (common elements are only listed once, between the two lists?), but a more formal definition would be useful. But if it's purely optional, you might just as well remove it completely.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, <s>47</s> 44 bytes

```
q~]e!{_2ew[{~_,@@\-,-}/]:+_W>{:W;:L}&}/];L:p
```

Explanation:

```
                                             e# L = [], W = -1
q~                                           e# Evaluate input
  ]                                          e# Wrap in array
   e!                                        e# Push all unique permutations
     {                               }/      e# For each permutation:
      _2ew                                   e#   Push all overlapping slices of length 2
           {         }/                      e#   For each slice:
            ~_,@@\-,-                        e#     Push number of common elements
          [            ]:+                   e#   Sum the number of common elements from all the slices
                          _W>{     }&        e#   If sum > W:
                              :W;            e#     Assign sum to W and pop off the stack
                                 :L          e#     Assign the permutation to L
                                       ];    e# Clear the stack
                                         L:p e# Print each list in L
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%5De!%7B_2ew%5B%7B~_%2C%40%40%5C-%2C-%7D%2F%5D%3A%2B_W%3E%7B%3AW%3B%3AL%7D%26%7D%2F%5D%3BL%3Ap&input=%5B5%206%2010%2015%5D%20%5B3%200%207%204%5D%20%5B49%2059%2029%5D%20%5B19%2029%2039%5D%20%5B9%2015%203%2010%5D).